# Calling a CSS from inside a Javascript on SharePoint from Script Editor

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint

I currently have a JavaScript code that I placed on a SharePoint Script Editor webpart. The idea is that if a query string is 1 it will call a SP CSS to hide the Advanced Search Webpart, otherwise display it.

I have the JavaScript retrieving successfully the value of the Query string, but how do I make it call the CSS from within a Javascript if statement.

The CSS that I need to call from Javascript is the following:

```
.srch-advancedtable {

visibility: hidden;
}
```

My JavaScript is the following, but it is not calling the CSS successfully:

```
<script>

function getParamValuesByName (querystring) {
var qstring = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 
1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < qstring.length; i++) {
var urlparam = qstring[i].split('=');
if (urlparam[0] == querystring) {
   return urlparam[1];
}
}
  }  var uid = getParamValuesByName('id');


document.write(uid);

if (uid == 1){

alert("the value is 1")

document.getElementById("srch-advancedtable").visibility = hidden;
}


</script>
```

How can I get this working properly?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Possibly your script is executing before the search webpart is rendered and hence document.getElementById("srch-advancedtable") would be returning undefined. Did you try changing the position of the script editor webpart inside the webpart zone so that it loads after the advanced search webpart? You can also consider using window.onload function to wait for DOM elements to load.

Comment: Hi Vineet, I'm not getting any errors. It simply will not call it. If I place the CSS directly on the webpart it works on page load, but I don't want that, it needs to run when I call it from JavaScript. I tried reordering the script editor to the bottom of the page and use the windows onload, it is not working. Do you have any other ideas that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it was a CSS Class not an ID. This worked:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("srch-advancedtable")[0].style.visibility= "hidden";
```